# Monaca: custom notification sound and small icon in Android with Onesignal

Tags: android, onesignal, monaca

I've started a Monaca project, imported the official Onesignal plugin and it's working OK.
The problem is that I couldn't find a way to send a custom sound and small icon in Android. I've place a mp3 file under /res/android/raw/ and a small white-only image in /res/android/screen but they aren't used.

I've tried to include and exclude file extensions in the notification to no avail. Also tried to place the files on the root fo the project.
Has anyone been able to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this ?

Comment: Did you find anything on this yet?

Answer (score 0):

add something like this in the config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
  <resource-file src="res/ios/sound/bird01.wav" />
  <hook type="before_compile" src="res/ios/sound/copy.js"/>
</platform>
```

in copy.js (`###########` is name of project):

```
module.exports = function(ctx) {
    var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
        path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path'),
        deferral = ctx.requireCordovaModule('q').defer(),
        shell = ctx.requireCordovaModule('shelljs');

    var dest = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/ios/###########.xcodeproj/Resources');
    var src = "res/ios/sound/*.*"
    shell.mkdir(dest)
    shell.cp(src, dest);
    console.log(shell.ls(dest));
    deferral.resolve();

    return deferral.promise;
};
```